# Convert BigInt To Int64 Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var categoryCounts = from p in ds.Tables["Emp"].AsEnumerable()
                     where p.Field<Int64>("ISBN") == Convert.ToInt64(txtIsbn.Text)
                     select p;
```

I'm storing ISBN as `bigint` in SQL Server but when isbn has more than 10 digits (e.g. 236765757568), it's not retrieved through LinQ and I have to use `Convert.ToInt64` method to convert it. But how to write it in LinQ below?

```
where p.Field<Convert.toInt64>("ISBN") == Convert.ToInt64(txtIsbn.Text) ///shows error
```

Comment: what error does it show? And please fix the text in your question, it is very hard to understand what is the problem.

Comment: @Rawling - did another pass at the question text, should be better. Although it is still far from understandable...

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing input text and type converting it within your database search code. Write a method that searches by ISBN that receives the Int64 parameter and when you call the method convert inputs into the correct parameters. Also, you seem to be forgetting to remove non-numeric characters from the ISBN (e.g. '-'). P.S. What kind of LINQ is that?

Comment: If the column in your database is a TSQL `BigInt` then this value will always be convertible to a .Net `Int64` or c# `long`. Is your question really, how can I parse a ISBN `string`/`varchar` into a `long`?

Comment: im able to get isbn that are 9 digits long but any isbn greater than 9 im not able to retrieve and it doesn't show any error message but only doesn't retieve isbn greater than 9 digits

Comment: isbn is bigint in database

Comment: I'm pretty sure either ISBN is of type Int in your database (int max value is 2,147,483,647) or you convert it to Int instead of Int64 (long).

Comment: no for sure its bigint in database